# 'AgencyRegistration' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, rest, object, attributes, attributeerror

I'm trying to create an endpoint using Django REST framework, but when I'm trying to get the data from the endpoint I'm getting the following error: AttributeError: 'AgencyRegistration' object has no attribute 'get'. Here's my code

models.py

```
`class AgencyRegistration(models.Model):
    agency_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tax_id_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=12)
    address_street = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    children_amount = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age_range = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program_benefit = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    organization_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    how_did_you_hear = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.agency_name`
```

views.py

```
`def agency_registration(request):
    agency_data = AgencyRegistration.objects.all()
    serializer = AgencyRegistrationSerializer(agency_data, many=True)
    return render(JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False))`
```

serializers.py

```
`class AgencyRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AgencyRegistration
        fields = [
            'id', 
            'agency_name', 
            'tax_id_number', 
            'address_street', 
            'city',
            'county',
            'state',
            'zip_code',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'title',
            'email',
            'phone',
            'children_amount',
            'age_range',
            'program_benefit',
            'organization_type',
            'how_did_you_hear'
        ]`
```

urls.py

```
`urlpatterns = [
    path('agency-registration/', views.AgencyRegistration),
]`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Model` as a `path` in `urlpatterns`. You can put there only views, like your `agency_registration`. It should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('agency-registration/', views.agency_registration),
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the issue

Comment: @RicardoMaldonado I'm glad :) if that answer is the correct one, please tick it as the one.